# Error thrown on trying to save a single rdf triple using rdf_save to a file

Tags: prolog, rdf, swi-prolog

Trying to save rdf triples to a file using the semweb package in swi-prolog, but keep getting an error and the triples are not saved correctly.

The following small code shows the problem with swi-prolog version 7.6.4 on Ubuntu Bionic.

PS: Please ignore the 'rdf:xyz' predicate as I tend to use it without needing to add new prefixes

```
:- use_module(library(semweb/rdf_db)).

assert_test :-
    rdf_bnode(Node),
    rdf_assert(Node, rdf:xyz, literal(type(xsd:string, "foobar"))),
    rdf_save('foo.xml').
```

I get the following error (showing top lines only):

```
ERROR: Unknown error term: save_attribute_value("foobar")
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [25] throw(error(save_attribute_value("foobar"),_980))
.
.
.
```

The file is created, but does not have the full triple.

An interesting side note, it works if I use `rdf_save_turtle` instead of `rdf_save`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Based on my first glance at the docs, I think you should try passing an atom instead of a Prolog string, i.e. `rdf_assert(Node, rdf:xyz, literal(type(xsd:string, foobar)))` or perhaps using just `literal(foobar)` or `literal(lang(en, foobar))`.

Comment: ugh! You are right (I should have read the documentation more carefully). Interesting though `rdf_save_turtle` works with the string. 
 
Not sure how I can accept a comment as an answer...If you could convert that into an official answer I can try and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my first glance at the docs, I think you should try passing an atom instead of a Prolog string, i.e.

```
rdf_assert(Node, rdf:xyz, literal(type(xsd:string, foobar)))
```

or perhaps using just `literal(foobar)` or `literal(lang(en, foobar))`.